# Getting exception when trying to add Outlook 2010 form region (.ofs file) to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: outlook, visual-studio-2012, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I get this message after I click "Finish" on new Form Region wizard

> An error occurred while processing file [file path].ofs
>
> Error: Unable to cast COM object of type System._ComObject to
>   interface type Microsoft.Vbe.Forms.UserForm. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID failed due to the following error: Interface no registered
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this was a compatibility issue with 64bit version of Office 2010. Out of desperation I uninstalled my 64 bit version and installed 32 bit, and after that I was able to create a form region based on .ofs file with no problems.